# Pig permission denied

Tags: hadoop, permissions, apache-pig

I wrote a simple script in pig and it runs good when run from terminal. 
However when i try to run the script from the browser using apache server, it throws the following error.

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - You don't have permission to perform the operation. Error from the server: dummy (Permission denied)
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. dummy (Permission denied)
```

Any ideas where to fix the problem? Well if it helps, nowhere in my script have I used anything called "dummy"!!!

P.S.: changed the permissions in the /tmp hdfs directory to 777, didn't help!!
         checked the permissions in the /tmp local directory has 777, didn't matter!!
         tried to use -Dpig.temp.dir to a directory in which apache has permission to write, didn't help!!
Please help, did I miss something?

Edit: Well worth mentioning: this error comes while i am running the script while checking for compilation of the pig script, i.e., pig -c ScriptName

```
2013-09-06 10:41:19,344 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.10.0 (r1328203) compiled Apr 19 2012, 22:54:12
2013-09-06 10:41:19,344 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /data/storage/pig-0.10.0/logs/pig_1378444279340.log
2013-09-06 10:41:19,658 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://[master]:9000
2013-09-06 10:41:19,743 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: [master]:9001
2013-09-06 10:41:19,866 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine - created tmp python.cachedir=/tmp/pig_jython_4266457116882300725
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/lib/tools.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/aspectjrt-1.6.5.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/aspectjtools-1.6.5.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-configurationhadoop-1.6.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-daemon-1.0.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-httpclient-3.0.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-logging-api-1.0.4.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-math-2.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/commons-net-1.4.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/core-3.1.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/guava-r09.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/hadoop-fairscheduler-0.20.203.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/hbase-0.94.4.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/hsqldb-1.8.0.10.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/hstreaming-all.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.0.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.0.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jasper-compiler-5.5.12.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jasper-runtime-5.5.12.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jets3t-0.6.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jsch-0.1.42.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/junit-4.5.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/kfs-0.2.2.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/mockito-all-1.8.5.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/oro-2.0.8.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/protobuf-java-2.4.0a.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/slf4j-api-1.4.3.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/xmlenc-0.52.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/zookeeper-3.4.5.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-2.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/home/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0/lib/jsp-2.1/jsp-api-2.1.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/data/storage/pig-0.10.0/lib/automaton.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/data/storage/pig-0.10.0/lib/jython-2.5.0.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/data/storage/pig-0.10.0/pig-0.10.0-withouthadoop.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/resources.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/rt.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/jsse.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/jce.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/charsets.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar'
*sys-package-mgr*: processing new jar, '/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_03/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar'
2013-09-06 10:41:28,086 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine - Register scripting UDF: pythonDefpyUDF.[UDF1]
2013-09-06 10:41:28,087 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.scripting.jython.JythonScriptEngine - Register scripting UDF: pythonDefpyUDF.[UDF2]
2013-09-06 10:41:28,266 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 1 time(s).
2013-09-06 10:41:28,421 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 1 time(s).
2013-09-06 10:41:28,578 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 1 time(s).
2013-09-06 10:41:29,665 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 1 time(s).
2013-09-06 10:41:29,712 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser - 'rm/rmf' statement is ignored while processing 'explain -script' or '-check'
2013-09-06 10:41:29,774 [main] WARN org.apache.pig.PigServer - Encountered Warning IMPLICIT_CAST_TO_FLOAT 1 time(s).
2013-09-06 10:41:29,814 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - You don't have permission to perform the operation. Error from the server: dummy (Permission denied)
2013-09-06 10:41:29,815 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. dummy (Permission denied)
Details at logfile: /data/storage/pig-0.10.0/logs/pig_1378444279340.log
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace ?

Comment: actually rest of it are common or particularly related to the script....only these two lines are why the script fails!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be permission issues for apache user.
While running following command `pig -c ScriptName`, check the output from both places.

1. Output From Shell
2. Output from script while executing through Apache server

Check the permission for log files as well, where pig is trying to write. This should help you to resolve this issue.

Comment: actually that was the trouble, was not able to find out where PIG was actually writing...!!anyways problem solved, pig while executing `pig -c` actually writes a dummy file "dummy" in the directory from which it was called and there "apache" user didn't have permission!!!! thank you for all the replies!!